# Deleting a user in unix

Tags: unix, users, deleting

Does deleting/removing a user automatically remove the user from all groups the user was a member in?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does.

Check out man pages for *userdel* command for more info, [for example here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel).

Additionally, pay attention to this part:

> **USERGROUPS_ENAB** (boolean)
>   If set to yes, userdel will remove the user's group if it contains no more members, and useradd will create by default a group with the name of the user.